# Nginx module not added after recompile

Tags: module, nginx, recompile

I just recompiled nginx in order to add the HttpStripModule module. (i followed this: https://serverfault.com/a/279536/111652)

this is the configure options i used to make / make install:

```
--conf-path=/etc/nginx/nginx.conf --error-log-path=/var/log/nginx/error.log --pid-path=/var/run/nginx.pid --lock-path=/var/lock/nginx.lock --http-log-path=/var/log/nginx/access.log --http-client-body-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/body --http-proxy-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/proxy --http-fastcgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/fastcgi --with-debug --with-http_stub_status_module --with-http_flv_module --with-http_ssl_module --with-http_dav_module --with-http_gzip_static_module --with-http_realip_module --with-mail --with-mail_ssl_module --with-ipv6 --add-module=/usr/src/gnosek-nginx-upstream-fair-5f6a3b7 --add-module=/usr/src/mod_strip
```

and then as soon as make install was completed, i did a nginx restart and ran `nginx -V`
and the output was:

```
--conf-path=/etc/nginx/nginx.conf --error-log-path=/var/log/nginx/error.log --pid-path=/var/run/nginx.pid --lock-path=/var/lock/nginx.lock --http-log-path=/var/log/nginx/access.log --http-client-body-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/body --http-proxy-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/proxy --http-fastcgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/fastcgi --with-debug --with-http_stub_status_module --with-http_flv_module --with-http_ssl_module --with-http_dav_module --with-http_gzip_static_module --with-http_realip_module --with-mail --with-mail_ssl_module --with-ipv6 --add-module=/build/buildd/nginx-0.7.65/modules/nginx-upstream-fair
```

As you can see... it didn't take my strip module. :(

what's going on here?

**UPDATE**: After all of this, I realized that my original install of nginx never was actually replaced.

This issue was solved by specifying the --sbin-path flag to the current location of nginx and then make installing. then the files were actually overwritten. After starting the nginx server now shows that it is the new version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The module is probably included.  Until recently, nginx's error logging could only print strings up to 2048 chars, so a really long ./configure string would get truncated when printed out.

Comment: thanks for your reply. I think i've actually uncovered something else. I just realized last night that my nginx version still shows 0.7.x whereas the install I did was 1.x.x. My original install was the apt-get package. and the "recompile" was from source. so somehow it didn't overwrite my original install, which i'm not sure how to aleviate

Comment: You can either apt-get remove the original package or use nginx -V to get all of the package's configure args and then duplicate them (especially --sbin-path)

Comment: should i stop the nginx process before doing that?

Comment: No, there's no need to stop it.  When building your own version, there's also a make upgrade target that will replace an existing binary without any downtime.

Comment: awesome. I was able to solve the problem. thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

Specifying `--sbin-path` to the configure command solved my issue as well.